# Алгоритм: Подбор маршрута по начальной и конечной остановкам с не более чем одной пересадкой. c++

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, поиск

Не могу понять какой алгоритм использовать.

задача:
Подбор маршрута по начальной и конечной остановкам с не более чем одной пересадкой между маршрутами.

объяснение (например):
есть 3 маршрута (помечены разными цветами)->[image: маршруты]

надо из "1" остановки попасть в "4" остановку.
для этого нам надо пересесть на "2" остановке на 2 маршрут, потом на "3" остановке пересесть на 3 маршрут и доехать до "4" остановки.

переменные:
есть массив

elem1 (1)(0) = 1

elem1 (1)(1) = 2

elem1 (2)(0) = 2

elem1 (2)(1) = 3

elem1 (3)(0) = 4

elem1 (3)(1) = 3

elem [№ маршрута] [№ п\п]. то есть в 1 маршруте остановка "1" - это первая по порядку, остановка "2" - вторая по порядку. и тп.

надо смотреть маршрут и искать на нем пересечения. если пересечений нет, то берем остановку, если на ней несколько маршрутов, то переходим на следующий маршрут и ищем пересечения там.
но надо найти минимальное количество пересечений между маршрутами.

вроде как надо использовать алгоритм поиска в глубину, но не простой.

Comment: Самое простое, пожалуй — поиск кратчайшего пути во взвешенном графе — типа алгоритма Дейкстры. При этом "пересадочные" вершины делятся на 2 с ребром веса 1 между ними; все остальные ребра — нулевые. В вашем примере, кстати, две пересадки...

Comment: Harry, для алгоритма дейкстры нужно указывать вес для путей. а как я это сделаю? мне это и не надо

Comment: Все нулевые, кроме пересадок.